# Basic Logical Implication Question

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to get my head around logical implication. This is a very basic question but it seems so trivial that I think I must have misunderstood it. Prove

$$\{\forall x\ (\alpha\to\beta) ,\forall x\ \alpha\}\models \forall x \ \beta$$

Okay, so for any structure $A$ and any variable assignment $s:V\to|A|$ such that
$$\models_A \forall x\ (\alpha\to\beta)[s] \ \& \models_A \forall x\ \alpha[s]$$
we must have
$$\models_A \forall x\ \beta[s].$$

Now either this is trivially true or I am not getting something. Any help?

Comment: I mean, it is trivially true in a sense (that was always my problem with these math logic questions). Ask yourself, why are you allowed to infer that $\models_A \forall x \beta [s]$ from $\models_A \forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) [s]$? You need a lemma: namely that every structure $B$ is such that $\models_B \forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)$. Then you can chase through the implications in the model.

Comment: Do you get the point of my answer? Whatever notation you wish to use, you have to distinguish between internal quantication (which is syntax) and external quantification over the elements in the model (which is semantics). The syntax is designed to capture the semantics but that is merely the intention and does not serve as a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so trivially true. The point of the exercise is to see whether you understand the distinction between syntax and semantics. Whether a formula is satisfied by a structure is recursively defined according to the syntax. To use a clearer notation:

---

If $A[s] \vDash \forall x\ ( α \to β )$ and $A[s] \vDash \forall x\ (α)$:

Given any element $c$ in $A$:

$A[s][x \mapsto c] \vDash ( α \to β )$ and $A[s][x \mapsto c] \vDash α$.   [by definition of satisfaction for $\forall$]

If $A[s][x \mapsto c] \vDash α$ then $A[s][x \mapsto c] \vDash β$.   [by definition of satisfaction for $\to$]

Thus $A[s][x \mapsto c] \vDash β$.   [by modus ponens **in the meta-system**]

Therefore $A[s] \vDash \forall x\ ( β )$.   [by definition of satisfaction for $\forall$]

---

Note what is happening. The syntax of the formal system was in fact designed to capture logical reasoning, so it is no surprise that the reasoning above looks very much like how it could be done inside the system, but this is the point; a semantic proof is not a priori the same as a syntactic proof. It turns out that $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ are the same for first-order logic, but that is a non-trivial result called the completeness theorem.